# No splitter widget in new separate window

Tags: interface

I am new to Blender and I am trying to find my way through its interface. I want to have several windows (I mean OS windows, not Blender windows). So I create a separate window by dragging splitter widget while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

The problem is there are no splitter widgets in the newly created OS window. So I can't have multiple blender windows in it. The new window does not have a Layout type drop down menu either. So how do I add new Blender windows in a new OS window? (Sorry if I'm using the wrong terms, but hopefully its clear what I am trying to achieve).
[image: No splitter widget!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you cannot split the windows is because you have one of your part of the User Interface maximized.

[image]

Once you go out of this maximization via pressing the "Back to previous" in the info header or by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> you can change your UI and create new windows.

Some other shortcuts to manipulate the User Interface.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd>: Maximize Window under mouse
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>: go to previous/next Layout

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't vote up your answer since I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you toggled your window full screen.

You can click the button "Back to previous" at the top, or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>UP arrow</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN arrow</kbd>, or again <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Space bar</kbd>) to toggle the window full screen / normal.

The "split view" widgets are only present when not in full screen.

Comment: Thank you. And I also apologize for not being able to vote up your answer as well.