# Materials menu gone

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

Somehow, all my menus disappeared, but I managed to get my tools and transfer menu back. Also, nothing will render without the materials menu. Here is a picture: [image]
Please tell me what to do!
Also, shift and space makes this.[image]

Comment: Press Shift+Space. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21697/unexpected-workspace-change and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8178/no-splitter-widget-in-new-separate-window, also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5887/layout-selector-missing

Comment: I think so, and no. Unmaximizing it brought up the frame menu. But thank you so much.

Comment: But it also brought up the materials menu. But how do I put the materials menu with the rest?

Comment: Shift+Space (or Ctrl+Up Arrow, or Ctrl+Down Arrow, whatever) will ever turn screen layout to one which was before maximizing. It can't change anything except for that. If you got layout on the second screenshot after unmaximizing then it was there before maximizing. *But* - note that window that gets maximized is the one you hover the mouse over while maximizing. Please clarify what do you mean by "put materials menu with the rest".

Comment: Nevermind, I think I fixed it by changing the window from timeline to 3D.

Comment: Also, I meant by having all the side menus together.