# Blender Viewport and Workspace Reset?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm new to blender and I tried to follow a tutorial and I'm pretty sure, I messed up the entire workspace of the blender.

Here's my current screenshot of the blender.

[image: Blender UI Messed Up]
How am i supposed to get back to the default UI of blender.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hit the back to previous button. (on header)

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8180/15543)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please save your file, close blender and re open it, open your blender file and un check the **Load UI** check box as shown below:

[image]

More details can be [check here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90440/lost-ui-properties-bar-and-cant-get-rid-of-other-bars/90442#90442)

Comment: Welcome, I am glad it worked for you, Thank you very much for accepting answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the Blender 2.8 UI overhaul, if you want to reset any workspace you can simply delete it:
[image]

And add it again:
[image]